# SMTPException in Django with GAE setting

Tags: django, google-app-engine, smtp, smtp-auth

I am trying to setup Django-invitation with my django project. It will deploy on the Google App Engine, and Google Cloud SQL. Now I have this issue "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server."

This is the settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='username@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I am waiting for your amazing advises.

**Edited**

If I remove the mail settings from settings.py I will get the following error:

```
SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

**Edited**

What configuration do I need for development for my django project and what configuration for production deployment for GAE ( Google App Engine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE comes with own internal mail-sending infrastructure. You can not define your own SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you mean I don't need to setup the emil service ??

Comment: That's correct. There are, however, certain limitations on the `from` address that you can use: either one of the admin accounts in GAE (Admin-Permissions) or a currently logged-in user (via GAE User service).